# TYPO3.CMS 9 LTS - cacheable extbase action but no cHash with new routing

Tags: php, typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

Any idea how to solve this? I have an extbase plugin, that has a list and a show action. Both should be cachable and the detail link should not contain a cache hash

I can not achieve this. As soon as i enable the caches i always get the same result for the detail action.

I configured the plugin to be cacheable:

```php
// add detail plugin
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.Extension',
    'SomePiName',
    [
        'ControllerName' => 'show',
    ],
    [],
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT
);
```

The routing config:

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyEnhanceName:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Extension
    plugin: SomePiName
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{localized_entry}/{slug}', _controller: 'ControllerName::show', _arguments: {'slug': 'uuid'} }
    defaultController: 'ControllerName::show'
    aspects:
      localized_entry:
        type: LocaleModifier
        default: 'show'
        localeMap:
          - locale: 'de_DE.*|de_AT.*|de_CH.*'
            value: 'detail'
          - locale: 'it_IT.*'
            value: 'dettaglio'
      slug:
        type: customType
```

My custom aspect works by mapping the foreign uuid on a generated slug, that is stored in a mysql-table i maintain.

I want a deeplink like:

`/path/to/page/show/here-comes-the-slug`

But i get

`/path/to/page/show/here-comes-the-slug?cHash=...`

So i added:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = "tx_extension_somepiname[uuid]";
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = "tx_extension_somepiname[controller]";
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = "tx_extension_somepiname[action]";
```

Now the link looks like:

`/path/to/page/show/here-comes-the-slug`

But as soon as i activate the caches i always get the same result.

So i need a cache hash calculation but i dont want the fu**er to be in the link...

Links are generated using ContentObjectRenderer->typolink_URL with the config:

```php
[
    "parameter" => "t3://myhandler?uuid=someuuid"
]
```

that handler translates to a subsequent call to ContentObjectRenderer->typolink_URL with the config:

```php
[
    "parameter" => "t3://page?uid=someconfiguredpageuid",
    "useCacheHash" => 0,
    "additionalParams" => "&tx_extension_somepiname[uuid]=uuid&tx_extension_somepiname[controller]=Controller&tx_extension_somepiname[action]=show"
]
```

So my situation is, that i can EITHER have a cacheHash and a correct result OR nor cacheHash with invalid results.

How is this meant to be done?

Comment: Can you explain / show what `customType` does exactly?

Comment: Well it implements the PersistedMappableAspectInterface, uses the SiteLanguageAwareTrait and translates uuids to slugs. Both uuid and the title - from which i generate the slug - are stored in a foreign api. The method generate translates a uuid to a slug and the method reslove translates a slug back to a uuid

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d8hwfAGG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i solved this, here the necessary steps:

1) Like Jonas Eberle suggested we remove the extbase arguments from excludedParameters.

2) Configure the details action as cacheable (remove controller->action combination from 2nd array of possible actions in extbase plugin registration / ext_localconf.php)

3) When using a custom aspect, implement the "StaticMappableAspectInterface". I did not find the relevant part in the core but it seems this interface is required! Just have a look at the PersistedAliasMapper.

Now it works...

Comment: Is it possible to do debugging in customAspect? I have created a customAspect , but the debugging is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You should not exclude parameters that actually distinguish page content from cHash generation. They are really only sane to use with external tracking parameters like `fbclid` etc.

Also don't use useCacheHash=0 if you rely on caching.

Rather configure the route enhancer to remove the `?cHash`.